# C# Having a method call inside Select statement causes multiple method calls

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

When running the below code

```
private static IEnumerable<Tester2> Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        yield return new Tester2(i);
}

private class Tester2
{
    public int Hey { get; set; }

    public Tester2(int hey)
    {
        Hey = hey;
    }
}

private class Tester3
{
    public int Hey3 { get; set; }

    public Tester3(int hey)
    {
        Hey3 = hey + 5;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<Tester3> Bar(IEnumerable<Tester2> lister)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world2!");
    return lister.Select(Convert);
}

private static Tester3 Convert(Tester2 tester)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world3!");
    var hey = "test";
    var result= hey.Map(x => new Tester3(tester.Hey)).First();
    return result;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  
    var x = Foo().ToList();

    var bar = Bar(x);
    
    foreach (var b in bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hmm2");
    }

    
    
}
```

I get my main thread calling the `Convert` method multiple times, as shown by the output:

```
Hello world!
Hello world2!
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
Hello world3!
Hmm2
```

Why is this? I've only ever seen behaviour like this when using `yield` and deferring execution, but never on simple `IEnumerable` methods - I would expect the behaviour to be that it would calculate an 'IEnumerable' when we go over it in the `for` loop and then evaluate it once. Obviously when I introduce `.ToList()` the issue goes away, but I'd like to understand the behaviour beforehand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It calls it for every item in the sequence.

Comment: What exactly was your expected output?

Comment: You have a Select on Bar(), if you add  .ToList() to it, the behaviour will change as well.

Comment: The whole point of a LINQ query is to process a list. Whatever the query contains will be applied to each item in that list. Consider if you were to call `Where` and used a method to determine whether to include or omit an item. How could that possibly work without calling that method for each item? `Select` works the same way, except that it transforms each item. How could you transform every item in a list without executing the transformation method for each item in the list?

Comment: `lister.Select(Convert)` is *also* lazily evaluated

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this?

`Select` means "Apply this function to each element". So it should be no surprise it is called one for each element. Since `Convert` takes a single element this is the only possible way for it to work.

`Select`, and most of the functions in LINQ, uses deferred execution / lazy evaluation. That is one of the main points with LINQ. Lazy evaluation is in no way restricted to iterator blocks (i.e. yield return-methods). Consider for example:

```
var one = new []{1, 2, 3}.Select(i => i.ToString()).First();
```

`.ToString()` will only be called *once*. And that can be quite useful. The length of the original list is irrelevant, since we only need the first item. It might even be infinitely long!

However, if you are using LINQ on regular lists, and not a database, some methods *will* need to evaluate the entire list once at least one value is required. For example `OrderBy`, since it needs to know all the elements in order to sort them. But the evaluation would still happen inside the foreach loop.